# PLS-00302: component 'PLCO_ID' must be declared

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

```
begin
        for implicit_cursor in
             (select * 
             from colo_proc_data p1 JOIN patient p2 ON p1.plco_id = p2.plco_id
             where  p1.BIOP = 1 AND p1.diag_stag = 2 AND p1.INTSTATC_CAT_LINK = 2 AND p1.PROC_CATC = 6 AND p1.proc_numc= 34 AND p1.PROC_RES = 2)
        loop
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                'PLCO_ID= ' || implicit_cursor.plco_id
                || '  ' || 'Age= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_AGE
                || '  ' || '#_of_days= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_DAYS
                || '  ' || 'income= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_INCOME);
       end loop;
end;
```

for the above code Getting this error:
PLS-00302: component 'PLCO_ID' must be declared.

```html
''''begin for implicit_cursor in (select * from colo_proc_data p1 JOIN patient p2 ON p1.plco_id = p2.plco_id where p1.BIOP = 1 AND p1.diag_stag = 2 AND p1.INTSTATC_CAT_LINK = 2 AND p1.PROC_CATC = 6 AND p1.proc_numc= 34 AND p1.PROC_RES = 2) loop DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
'PLCO_ID= ' || implicit_cursor.plco_id || ' ' || 'Age= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_AGE || ' ' || '#_of_days= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_DAYS || ' ' || 'income= '|| implicit_cursor.SQX_INCOME); end loop; end; / '''' for the above code Getting this error: PLS-00302:
component 'PLCO_ID' must be declared.
```

Comment: edit question and show table definitions.

Comment: Since you use `select *` and you join two tables by the same column `plco_id`, you should get `PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names`. Please, provide a complete code including table definitions